# Longboard wheel help

Tags: maintenance, skateboarding, longboarding

I just ordered my first longboard and was just wondering if I can put these wheels on these trucks and if you know how to do it that would be very helpful too, thanks!

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Longboard-Skateboard-Wheels-Red-Black-83A-76x53mm-/121214682680?pt=AU_Skateboarding&hash=item1c38f54638&_uhb=1
[image]

[40" Pintail Longboard Cruiser Skateboard: Orange](http://www.oo.com.au/40-101-6cm-Concave-Pintail-_P202979.cfm)

[image: 40" Pintail Longboard Cruiser Skateboard: Orange]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - they can be used. The bearing size is generally the same (with some exceptions, but those are always flagged up as such)

All you need is a wrench/spanner or pliers.

- Undo the axle bolts holding on the existing wheels
- Slip the old wheels off
- Slip the new wheels on
- Tighten up the bolts

Enjoy.